# User cannot see schema- are all of my grants correct?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My user (analystperson) cannot see the Development schema (and the tables/views inside this schema) at all. I have given all of the grants below but they still cannot see it. I have rerun everything below- it's weird as the user can see other schemas on this database but just not this one.

GRANT ROLE **ROLE_USER_GROUP_ANALYST** TO USER **analystperson**;

Grant OPERATE ON WAREHOUSE **QUERY_WH** TO ROLE **ROLE_USER_GROUP_ANALYST**;

GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA **DEV_DW.DEVELOPMENT** to role **ROLE_USER_GROUP_ANALYST**;

GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA **DEV_DW.DEVELOPMENT** TO ROLE **ROLE_USER_GROUP_ANALYST**;

GRANT SELECT ON ALL VIEWS IN SCHEMA **DEV_DW.DEVELOPMENT** TO ROLE **ROLE_USER_GROUP_ANALYST**;

GRANT SELECT ON FUTURE TABLES IN SCHEMA **DEV_DW.DEVELOPMENT** TO ROLE **ROLE_USER_GROUP_ANALYST**;

GRANT SELECT ON FUTURE VIEWS IN SCHEMA **DEV_DW.DEVELOPMENT** TO ROLE **ROLE_USER_GROUP_ANALYST**;

I feel like I have given the user everything via assigning it the ROLE_USER_GROUP_ANALYST role.

Am I missing something?

Comment: you need to grant usage on the database as well

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve this by checking the default role of the user. This user had a different default role and once I granted permissions to this default role, the issue was resolved.